# .NET Core GetFromJsonAsync exits with no error or debugging information

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to debug a request by `GetFromJsonAsync` which is supposed to fetch data from a Flask API and convert to JSON within a .NET Core cli app.

The issue I am having however is that after performing the request the cli app simply exits with no error. I have tried implementing try/catch block but nothing shows up there.

the Flask endpoint builds jsonifies a number of uuids and messages from Postgres and returns them to the client.

As `GetFromJsonAsync` is asynchronous I have tried making the Flask endpoint likewise but that has not seemed to help at all. The latter works fine and has been validated with curl.

I know the call executes as I can see it in my web server logs.

A similar call which simply returns plain javascript object `{"foo": "bar"}` works fine which is why I think this could by an async issue but I cannot see any errors etc to troubleshoot. I have placed a breakpoint on the `foreach` after the call but this is never hit.

What am I missing here?

```
    public static async void GetMessages()
    {
        ConfigureHeaders();
        try
        {
            var client = Client;
            var res = await Client.GetFromJsonAsync<Received>(Url + "/api/chat/message"); // stops here
            foreach (var c in res!.messages) // breakpoint here is never hit
                Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }


public class Received
{
    public Dictionary<string,string> messages { get; set; }
}
```

Flask

```
@message.get("/api/chat/message")
@csrf.exempt
async def get_messages():
    new_msgs = {}
    msgs = await get_unreplied() # DB gets called from another function here
    try:
        for m in msgs:
            new_msgs[m.id] = m.message
        if len(new_msgs) != 0:
            return jsonify(new_msgs)
        else:
            return jsonify("no messages")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

This returns...

{
  "id_foo1": "message_bar1", 
  "id_foo2": "message_bar2"
}
```

Comment: If you use async, follow these rules.  1) Add `Async` as a suffix to the function name. 2) return type should be `Task` or `Task<>`, never void. 3) If you see a function that has an Async suffix, `await` it (ignoring the context switch overhead for now). 4) any `Async` function should have a final parameter of `CancellationToken`, and you should use this to pass to any other async function you are calling.

Comment: Good addition by @Neil: but to clarify: don't use `async void GetMessages` use `async Task GetMessages` whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best guess: your `Main` function is not awaiting the call to `GetMessages`

```
public async Task<int> Main(string []args)
{
    await GetMessages();  
}
```

Comment: That was it. The call there was 3 or so methods deep from Main(). I had to move back up the chain and make everything async